# An error happen while trying to get the block number getting this error while trying to deploy contract on sepolia testnet

Tags: blockchain

An error happen while trying to get the block number {

```
jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: '560dd4aa-2044-40f2-99bf-18c38672cfc0',
  error: {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT',
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
}
```

first time deploy it works prefectly but now i am trying to deploy it not working
why this hapened